# Powershell get-eventlog message column is too short

Tags: powershell, event-log

When using powershell to retrieve info about events Message column gets trimmed and is too short:

> Index Time          Type Source                EventID Message
>   ----- ----          ---- ------                ------- -------
>       2 Sep 18 12:50  Info yaddayadda             0 Class: Controllers.BasketController...
>       1 Sep 18 12:50  Info yaddayadda             0 Class: Controllers.BasketController...

Is it possible to see full message?

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: both worked for me: `.... | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap` &  `..... | select -ExpandProperty message` (put one or the other at the end of your query)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are seeing the default table format for the type (this will be define in one of the install (`x.format.ps1.xml` files).

You can:

- Use a wider console window, the final column fills the available space.
- Add `format-table -wrap` to the end of pipeline and PSH will wrap the text of the final column.
- Add `format-table -auto` to the end of the pipeline and PSH will adjust all the columns to fit (but needs to see all the data first, so you will not get incremental results).
- Use both `-auto` and `-wrap`.
- Specify the table format you want. Specify a list of properties to display. Or a list of hashes defining the columns (in this case each can have its own label, alignment, width and expression). See `help format-table -full` for details.

Comment: "get-eventlog -logname Foo format-table -auto -wrap" did exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I was trying to add "format-table -auto -wrap" to the end of  the query and was getting an error ("Cannot convert value format-table to type System.Int64"). Worked around that by modifying the query to look like this: Get-EventLog -LogName Application -After (get-date).addDays(-7) -Message "*custom message*" | format-table -wrap > file.txt

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the methods proposed above you can use the `-ExpandProperty` as follows if you only want to extract the error message:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 10 -EntryType Warning | select -ExpandProperty message
```

This will extract the entire error message.

Answer (score 6):

Pipe to Format-List.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Open the Command Prompt window and click on the leftmost top corner.
>Select Properties
>Go to Layouts tab
>Increase the width and height of the Screen Buffer size and Window size.
```

This works.

Comment: This is not the right answer as you will get to the limit of the new screen size.